# mean of vector with at least n (>1) non-missing values, R

Tags: r, mean, na.rm

I want to calculate the mean of a vector with missing values only if at least a number of values exist. So for example if only one (or less than five) value(s) are non-missing, I want to return NA, but if I have at least two (or more than five) non-missing values, I want to return the mean.

How could I achieve this using `mean()`?

The standard behavior of `mean()` is to either return the NA if there is at least one value missing or return the mean if at least one value is non-missing (I want something in between):

```
x = c(1, 2, NA, NA)

mean(x)   # returns NA if there is one (or more) value missing
[1] NA

mean(x, na.rm = T) # returns the mean of the existing values (if there is at least one)
[1] 1.5
```

Ideally I would want a solution that would work for a `tapply(..., FUN = mean)` scenario.

Comment: what about an `ifelse(!is.na(x) > 5, mean(x), NA)`? should work in a `tapply` call as well...

Comment: @drmariod this won't work. You should use `sum(is.na(x)) > 5` instead of `!is.na(x) > 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way using the `ifelse`function:

```
x <- c(rep(NA_real_, 5), 1:4)

mean(x, na.rm = T)
[1] 2.5
ifelse(sum(!is.na(x)) > 5, mean(x, na.rm = T), NA_real_)
[1] NA
```

Comment: Thank you Cettt and drmariod, this is very helpful!! :-)
I can easily adapt this to my problem.
However, to be over correct, you did not exactly answer my question: Your code calculates the mean if the number of missing values is smaller than 5. 
I was after a solution that calculates the mean if the number of non-missing values is higher than n (which could be 5). I think approaching it from the latter direction is more useful.
If you could adapt the answer to this, I will be more comfortable to accept the answer.

Comment: sorry. didn't read the question carefully enough. I modiefied my answer

Comment: Now your example doesn't really match the problem anymore. However you answered my question. I will accept it anyway. Thanks, again!